# SQL Query to replace character based on join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called service entry which has a field called part description, Sample data is as follows:

```
**dbo.ServiceEntry**
ID      PartDescription
1200  60009 ~ Slide Error ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | 60011 ~ RV loader - Pick/Place Homing Error ~ L 0 ~ P 0
```

I then have a table called ServiceEntryPart which has a 1 to many relationship, one service entry can have multiple parts in it, hence the service entry part table

```
**dbo.ServiceEntryPart**
ID  ServiceEntry   PartID   OldPartID
1    1200          5000     60009
2    1200          5500     60011


**dbo.Part**
ID     Description                           OldPartID
5000   New Slide Description                 60009
5500   Xyz                                   60011
```

Im trying to write a script to update the partdescription column in the ServiceEntry Table so the expected results will look like following with the new part id. so its basically just replacing the old part ids with the new ones

**OLD OUTPUT**

```
60009 ~ Slide Error ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | 60011 ~ RV loader - Pick/Place Homing Error ~ L 0 ~ P 0
```

**NEW OUTPUT**

```
5000 ~ New Slide Description ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | 5500 ~ Xyz ~ L 0 ~ P 0
```

I need some help with the script.query to update this fields with the new part id if present:

```
 1. Get the existing field
 DECLARE @PartDescription VARCHAR(8000)
 SELECT @PartDescription =  PartDescription FROM
 ServiceEntry

 2. UPDATE ServiceEntry
    SET PartDescription
```

Comment: Why did you create a one-to-many relation to just turn around and de-normalize your data?

Comment: thats not my requirment. The part description concatenated column is used for display on a page. I know normalization, if you see i have a service entry part table. At this point I cannot change the application code, this update of that column is just going to happen once

Comment: The concatenation should happen in the application not the database, however, I understand that at some point it becomes harder to make these changes. I just want you to be aware that this is a problematic design (one of the problems that would arise, is the problem you are running into right now)

Comment: I agree, I certainly did not design this table and there is a lot of C# code that If I were to normalize this column, I wont be able to meet my deadline. If I was asked to update this column with new parts frequently then I would certainly normalize but at this time I just want to update that column and having difficulty since its a bad design from start and thats why I am here to ask you the experts for some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ServiceEntry TABLE(
        ID INT,
        PARTDescription VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @ServiceEntryPart TABLE(
        ID   INT,
        ServiceEntry   INT,
        PartID INT,
        OldPartID INT
)

DECLARE @Part TABLE(
        ID  INT,
        [Description]  VARCHAR(50),
        OldPartID VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @ServiceEntry SELECT 1200, ''

INSERT INTO @ServiceEntryPart SELECT 1, 1200, 5000, 60009
INSERT INTO @ServiceEntryPart SELECT 2, 1200, 5500, 60011

INSERT INTO @Part SELECT 5000, 'New Slide Description', 60009
INSERT INTO @Part SELECT 5500, 'Xyz', 60011

UPDATE @ServiceEntry
SET PARTDescription = 
        ( 
            SELECT  CAST(p.ID AS VARCHAR)+ ' ~ ' + p.Description + ' ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | '
            FROM    @Part p INNER JOIN  
                    @ServiceEntryPart ep ON p.ID = ep.PartID
            WHERE   ep.ServiceEntry = se.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) 
FROM    @ServiceEntry se

UPDATE @ServiceEntry
SET PARTDescription = LEFT(PARTDescription, LEN(PARTDescription) -2)

SELECT *
FROM @ServiceEntry
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So assuming this is the old one, Im just interested in replcating the ID and the part description and anything after that will stay the same.  1057 ~ Reagent Cartridge ~ 1,2 ~ ed |  1094 ~ RV ~ 1,2,3 ~ dqw . So in this the id and part description will only be replaced with the new ones

Comment: is there a reason you can't just rebuild the whole string with the new values?

Comment: well I can rebuild the old string but having this ' ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | '
in the sql, not every part will have. I think I didn explain the question correctly. Your answer is a good path for me, Ill mark it as correct shortly

Answer (score 0):

If you can select like this:

```
SELECT SE.ID, SE.PartDescription
FROM ServiceEntryPart SEP
JOIN ServiceEntry SE ON SE.ID = SEP.ServiceEntry
JOIN Part P ON P.ID = SEP.PartID
```

You should be able to update like this:

```
UPDATE SE
SET SE.PartDescription = P.Description
FROM ServiceEntryPart SEP
JOIN ServiceEntry SE ON SE.ID = SEP.ServiceEntry
JOIN Part P ON P.ID = SEP.PartID
```

But check that you're pulling the right records.

The concatenated PartDescription in ServiceEntry looks questionable to me.  You might be better off pulling that information together using joins on the normalized tables whenever you need it, rather than storing it in denormalized form.  You won't be able to do much with it in that form.

Comment: well the part description concatenated column is for display on a page. The service entr part table is normalized. at this point my requirment is to only update that column even though the design was done by some one else